# Графика на чистом c++?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, winapi, графика

Когда пишется ОС припиливают API. С помощью Win32 API можно создавать оконные приложения. Но ведь когда у них не было никакого API они могли что-то нарисовать на экране, а затем собрать в кучу и делать оконные приложения. Как собственно средством только ЯП сделать окно, например или что-то нарисовать? Как это делали создатели ОС?

UPD. Нашёл интересный пост на данную тему [здесь](https://seenaburns.com/2018/04/04/writing-to-the-framebuffer/)

Comment: Ваш вопрос носит чисто академический интерес?

Comment: @Kromster в целом да, но я бы все же хотел технических подробностей и примеров

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Можно рисовать на [фреймбуфере](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_framebuffer)(fbdev) или [напрямую](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Rendering_Infrastructure) в видеокарту (dri).

Очень длинная статья по теме:
http://betteros.org/tut/graphics1.php

В современных компютерах можно написать графику шейдерами и выводить на тот же фреймбуфер.

В противовес АПИ и фреймворкам, такой вывод популярен на встраиваемых системах и тонких клиентах.

Рекомендую посмотреть на [Yocto](https://www.yoctoproject.org). Там собирается очень минимальный Линукс и есть шаблоны для сборки разных библиотек для работы на низком уровне.

Answer (score 7):

Средством только ЯП не получится. Еще понадобится окружение, в котором ЯП будет работать. ОС по сути и есть это окружение. Без ОС - как минимум вам нужен будет загрузчик, который включит устройства ввода-вывода (клавиатура, мышь, видеокарта и дисплей), и устройство, с которого загрузится ваша программа — (дисковод, жесткий диск, CD-ROM, флэшка или сетевуха), найдет вашу программу на одном из устройств и передаст ей управление. После чего вы сможете рисовать, т.к. загрузчик, образно говоря, передаст вам вместе с управлением драйвер видеокарты в качестве модуля для вашей программы.
Можете поставить себе виртуальную машину и поэкспериментировать с этим.

Comment: Т.е. имеется в виду, что нужно написать драйвер для видеокарты и скомпановать с выводом на дисплей?

Comment: сначала всё так придётся написать загрузчик) https://habrahabr.ru/post/173705/ в гугле можно про это почитать

Answer (score 7):

1. писать в порты видеоадаптера
2. BIOS обычно имеет прерывания для вывода
   точки на экране с заданными атрибутами.

Никакого окружения не нужно. Никакой ОС не нужно. API пишите сами. Удобнее сначала сделать компилятор к-нибудь языка. На ассемблере муторно.
ОС будет нужна для отрисовки более сложных вещей и работой с памятью. Хотя можно и без нее:)
Обратил внимание,что Вас интересует получение окошечек именно на С++. Но С++ все-равно должна использовать либо библиотеки написанные на асме, либо ассемблерные вставки для вывода. И мы приходим к п.1., т.е. пишем напрямую в видюху. 
P.S. что есть ЯП? ЯПлакалъ?

Comment: ЯП = язык программирования