# Простейшая графика в C++

Tags: c++

Недавно заинтересовался, как вывести ответ не в консоль, а в окно, но вдруг понял, что не могу даже окно создать. До этого работал только с консолью. Как понять, как работать с окнами и изображениями внутри? Может, есть какая-нибудь литература?

Comment: Пробовали искать что-то перед вопросом?

Comment: Да, но ничего не понятно , всюду просто куча функций и я запутался , поэтому решил спросить здесь

Comment: В стандартном C++ ничего для этого нет. Нужно использовать API конкретной ОС или сторонние библиотеки...

Comment: на windows можно с помощью win api создавать окна

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/675510/398802

Comment: Как уже сказали, требуется какое-то окружение. Из переносимых — Qt, FLTK.

Comment: Гуглите книги по Qt. Многие признают его одним из лучших окружений для работы с окнами и графикой на C++ .

Answer (score -3):

Для простой в программировании графики воспользуйтесь MSVC или Qt. Рисуйте на окне хоть простые линии и круги https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html, хоть более сложные вещи с кнопками и картинками

Comment: msvc это же компилятор. Или вы про другое?

Comment: это сдк с компилятором, редактором, рисовалкой окон мышкой и апи к виндовым формам.

Comment: А как отдельно компилятор назвать тогда?

Comment: Microsoft C++ (MSVC) compiler - называют в документации.

Comment: Ну так — MSVC, получается

Comment: скобки к словам до скобок. MSVCС тогда уж)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111950/discussion-between-eri-and-dim0n).